# Problem configuring Application Insights monitoring on Spring Boot Admin

Tags: azure-application-insights

I've been asked to configure azure application insights for our Spring Boot Admin as a POC. Previously I had successfully configured App Insights on a Spring Petclinic app, I replicated the same configuration on both apps but Application Insight doesnt work on the Spring Boot Admin app.

Here is the config I used :

In the pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>applicationinsights-web-auto</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

AI-Agent.xml, ApplicationInsights.xml and the java agent jar file are all in the same repository "/opt/apm".

I use this command to start the application java -javaagent:/opt/apm/applicationinsights-agent-2.5.0.jar
 -Dapplicationinsights.configurationDirectory=/opt/apm/ -jar - app.jar

On the pet clinic I can see logs like these :

```
AI: INFO 29-11-2019 18:21:45.136+0000, 1(main): heartbeat is enabled
AI: TRACE 29-11-2019 18:21:45.139+0000, 1(main): Registering PC 'DeadLockDetector'
AI: TRACE 29-11-2019 18:21:45.139+0000, 1(main): Registering PC 'JvmHeapMemoryUsedPerformanceCounter'
AI: TRACE 29-11-2019 18:21:45.139+0000, 1(main): Registering PC 'GCPerformanceCounter'
```

But on the Spring Boot Admin app I can only see this :

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields 
(jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/xstream-1.4.10.jar!/) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access 
operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I get the same kind of logs on my PetClinic app, but a bit different :

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.core.util.Fields (jar:file:/server.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/applicationinsights-web-auto-2.5.0.jar!/) to field java.util
.TreeMap.comparator
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I think it might be related to some dependency my Spring Boot Admin app has.

I hope you can give me some clues.

Thank you